# angular strap modal is not showing html template

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

this is the modal button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-animation="am-fade-and-scale" data-template="templates/AddNewItem.tpl.html" bs-modal="modal">
                    Custom Modal
                    <br>
                    <small>(using data-template)</small>
                </button>
```

in the folder 'templates' I have the "AddNewItem.tml.html" (I also checked in the "network" tab of google chrome developer tools, that it founds the file).

the  "AddNewItem.tml.html" is built as instructed [here](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.tpl.html).
this is how it looks:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" ng-show="title">
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="$hide()">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" ng-bind="title">My Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" ng-bind="content">
            My Content

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$hide()">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when I press the button, I get an empty modal dialog without any content.

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/dFkvjvEWowsACBmOTHE3?p=preview)

Comment: could you provide plunked with this code please?

Comment: please:
http://plnkr.co/edit/dFkvjvEWowsACBmOTHE3?p=preview
(also added a link in the original question)

Comment: Where is the code in your plnkr that is supposed to trigger the modal?

Comment: this is the angular directive (angular strap modal), that triggers the showing of the modal

Comment: I guess that you've posted wrong plunker.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late answered, but here it goes.
The `bs-modal` tag in html must reference an object in the controller.

```
myApp.controller('modalController', function($scope){
  $scope.modal = {
    "title": "Title",
    "content": "Hello Modal. This is a custom message!"
  };
});
```